# Update singular value in flutter dart redux

Tags: redux, flutter, dart

I have the following BuiltMap get map; in the BowlerState. It contains BowlerEntity objects. 
I want to update a particular bowler in this map. My BowlerUpdate action contains the values that need to be updated in that particular bowler. 
How do I do so? I need to modify the below reducer to do so.

One reducer is like this

```
BowlerState _updateBowlerAge(
    BowlerState bowlerState, SaveBowlerAgeSuccess action) {
  return bowlerState.rebuild((b) => b
      ..map[action.bowler.id] = action.bowler
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you use `build_runner` package?

Comment: Yes @MichaelYuwono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()` to replace the desired BowlerEntityBuilder.

```
BowlerState _updateBowlerAge(BowlerState state, SaveBowlerAgeSuccess action) {
  final newMap = state.map[action.bowler.id].toBuilder()
    ..replace(action.bowler);
  return state.rebuild((b) => b
    ..map.replace(newMap));
}
```